# How to make a rectangle centered AND responsive with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a board-game adoption for web. 
I want to use Bootstrap to make the elements responsive.

The main element of the game is a rectangle (the game board). This shall appear centered in all display-sizes and with a bit of margin to all sides.

Which attributes and CSS-rules do I have to apply?
Shall I use a normal container or container-fluid?

Would it be enough to make one column within the container / row and give it a class of "col-xs-12"?

As far as I know this would be applied to all devices beginning from the smallest to the largest upwards.

What I have tried so far:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ababab;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.board {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background-color: teal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 board">The game-board</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can see an example : you dont need col-xs-12 . You have only to set contaier-fluid in the parent and some padding in div wrapper with box-sizing:border-box . Row is for reset the standard padding of container and col classes with negative margin. It's your decision if you want to .

```css
html,body{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
.container-fluid,.row{height:100%;background-color:grey}
.board-container{padding:40px;box-sizing:border-box}
.board{background-color:teal;height:100%;padding:40px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row board-container">
    <div class="board">Board Game</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ababab;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.board {
  margin: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background-color: teal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 board">The game-board</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  html,body{
    height:100%;
  background:#FF3366;
  }

.container {
   width:100%;
    height:100%;
 
 
}
.row{
   height:100%;
   margin:30px 30px 30px 30px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: teal;
   border: 1px solid black;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">The game-board</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Try this one.